# Clion: Gtest TEST_F not working with std::cin

Tags: c++, input, googletest, clion

I'm trying to send in an input value within the CLion + Gtest system (MacOS 10.14.4), but I get infinite "loading icon" and cannot type in anything into the "Run" window.

I created the tests using a tutorial. Normal tests work flawlessly, only *std::cin* refuses to work. *std::cin* works outside the test framework, when just opening a basic project and immediately using it. For this simple example, I only use one file "test.cpp", so nothing else is imported.

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

using testing::Eq;
using namespace std;

namespace {
    class basicTest : public testing::Test {
    public:
        basicTest() {
        }
    };


    TEST_F(basicTest, test1) {
        cout << "\nWrite a number here: " << endl;
        int i;
        cin >> i;
        cout << "You wrote " << i << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Running this produces the following:

[image]

The icon keeps spinning, but there is nowhere for me to write an input. In my original code, the first cout did not even output, so it's just a blank screen until I terminate it with the stop button.

Stopping early produces "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)" but I don't think it's relevant.

I have not tried to use debug mode because it's not compatible with my MacOS version (that's another problem I'll fix eventually).

Comment: Have you tried just running your test binary in a terminal (outside of CLion)?

Comment: I've not used the terminal to compile before on MacOS or CMake. However I did use cxxtest and the terminal on my Windows before moving over.

Comment: Temporary fix: simply using the standard main() for that one test with the input. Definitely not convenient but it does the job for the assignment.